# Express the complex number given in the form a+ib.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Express the complex number given in the form a+ib.

$(1 - \sqrt{2}i)(2 + \sqrt{3}i)$

I'm  confused a little bit.
I made it to $2 + \sqrt{3}i - 2\sqrt{2}i - \sqrt{2}i\sqrt{3}i$    , but I don't know what to do next. Help please!

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{2i}$ or $\sqrt 2 i$?

Comment: it is first option

Comment: Note that $\sqrt {2i}$ is actually 2 numbers but not one, you sure?

Comment: ups, yep. I made a mistake. only number 2 under the root

Comment: $\sqrt 2 i \sqrt 3 i = \sqrt 6 i^2 = -\sqrt 6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z=(1-\sqrt{2}i)(2+\sqrt{3}i) =2+\sqrt{3}i-\sqrt{3}i\sqrt{2}i-2\sqrt{2}i =2-\sqrt{6}i^2+
-i(2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})= 2+\sqrt{6}+(-2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})i $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It isn´t hard if you use $i^2=-1$

$(1-\sqrt2\cdot i)\cdot (2+\sqrt 3\cdot i)=2+\sqrt 3\cdot i-2\sqrt 2\cdot i-\sqrt{6}\cdot i^2$